# Vim - yank into search register

Tags: vim, editor, vi

Is there any easy/quick way to "yank" into vim's "last search" register ("/)?

From the vim documentation, it appears that the answer is no, but that it can be assigned via a "let" command:

```
It is writable with ":let", you can change it to have 'hlsearch' highlight
other matches without actually searching.  You can't yank or delete into this
register.
```

Ideally what I'd like to do is something like:

```
"/5yw
```

which would yank the next 5 words under the cursor & put them in the last search buffer

Alternatively, if there is a way to search for the contents of a named register, that would work too.  In other words, if I could do:

```
"A5yw
```

and then search for what is in register A, that would work too.

The closest I can come is to yank into a named register & then copy that register into the last search register, e.g.

```
"A5yw
:let @/=@A
```

At the risk of making a long question longer, I want to state that it's not always 5 words I'd like to "yank & search" -- sometimes it's 17 characters, sometimes it's to the end of the line, etc... so a hard-coded macro doesn't give me the flexibility I'd want.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

After pressing `/` to enter a search string, you can then use `Ctrl-R` and then type the letter representing the register that you want to use.

eg.

- First, `"Ayw`    to yank a word into register A
- Then,  `/ ^R A`  to put the contents of register A into the search string.

Comment: This of course works, but it sounds like the OP may not actually want to search, just get the highlighting. If that's the case, a custom operator would be the way to go.

Comment: Super - thanks ar... that's exactly what I needed (well, under the constraints that the perfect solution is actually not possible in the first place.)  Thanks for the concise solution.

Comment: @Jefromi - thanks for your answer (below) and your help.  Sorry, I might not have been clear enough in my original question, but I actually wanted this for searching & I actually have the highlighting disabled.  Thanks for the input though!

Comment: @Dan - Ah, cool. If you're obsessive enough to want to cut out the few extra keystrokes, you could still look into the custom operator, but the `^R` method is plenty good - I use it all the time.

Comment: Just a comment... "Ayw does not yank the word into register 'A'.... it appends the thing being yanked onto the 'a' register.

Comment: +1 been looking for this for a while, perfect solution to the problem I was trying to solve - thanks.

Comment: For the sake of clarity - vim uses the case of the register to determine whether it's appending to or replacing the contents, so `"ayw` (lower case) would replace the contents of register 'a', while `"Ayw` would append to register 'a'

Answer (score 52):

If you did not use any register to store the yanked text vim uses `0` register. You can search for that by typing `Ctrl-R 0` after `/`.

A more complicated example. Say that you want to search in another buffer for the text inside quotes which is under the cursor right now:

- You can do that with `yi"` (yank inner quote)
- Go to the buffer where you want to search
- Type `/Ctrl-R 0`

Comment: I found this solution more useful than a'r's since repeatedly conducting `"Ayw`  produces an appended string in the register A. But simply typing `yw` and then typing `Ctrl-R 0` after `/` always gives exactly what I yanked.

Comment: This solution is better. Most of the time I do not specify the register when yanking.

Answer (score 10):

I'm using following code for that:

```
vnoremap <silent>* <ESC>:call VisualSearch('/')<CR>/<CR>
vnoremap <silent># <ESC>:call VisualSearch('?')<CR>?<CR>

    function! VisualSearch(dirrection)
        let l:register=@@
        normal! gvy
        let l:search=escape(@@, '$.*/\[]')
        if a:dirrection=='/'
            execute 'normal! /'.l:search
        else
            execute 'normal! ?'.l:search
        endif
        let @/=l:search
        normal! gV
        let @@=l:register
    endfunction
```

Comment: In case it's not clear, this allows you to select some text in visual mode, and use * or # to search for that text.

Answer (score 8):

Searching for a selection:

if you want to first yank a section of a line, then use "v" and move with cursors until you have marked what you want, then press y for yank and now the selection is in register 0

you can then type `/Ctrl-R 0`

Answer (score 5):

So basically an extended version of the # and * commands, right? It sounds like you want to define a custom operator (a command that expects a motion). I've never actually done this, but I did find a [plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2692) which looks like it might make it easier to do so. There are some examples provided.